# cannot map mssql timestamp column to hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying to read a timestamp column in mssql which is stored in timestamp  but it was in hexadecimal type , i was trying to map it using spring jpa hibernate but it was throwing error below is my column type in hibernate

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column( name ="last_upadtedon")
private Date  updatedon;
```

it is throwing exception while trying to read from table, i have tried all the desired  method but nothing seems to work for me how to read a timestamp column in hibernate. what did i  miss here

Comment: A timestamp data type is SQL Server is actually a binary rowversion and has no relation to date or time. The column name `last_updatedon` suggests the wrong column data type is being used. Should probably be datetime or datetime2.

Comment: Can you share your stack trace as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server timestamp is not the same as other timestamps. You should use `DATETIME2` instead.

> [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. **To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.**
>
> **The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.**

---

> [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)
>
> SQL Server Database Engine type | .NET Framework type
>
> timestamp                       | Byte[]